# A comment for a group of variables

Tags: fortran, doxygen, fortran90

I am trying to use a comment for a group of variables in documentation of a Fortran 90 code using doxygen 1.7.3:

```
!> The parameters defined to convert R to Q
real(wp),allocatable :: A(:)
integer,allocatable :: B(:)
integer,allocatable :: C(:)
```

However, this would would only produce a comment for the first variable. How can I have the comment for all three?

**Update:**
Just as a follow-up to @Alexander Vogt's reply:
The result looks very good if the following is used:

```
!> @name groupname 
!! The parameters defined to convert R to Q
!> @{
real(wp),allocatable :: A(:)
integer,allocatable :: B(:)
integer,allocatable :: C(:)
!> @}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group variables using `@defgroup <name> <description> @{ ... @}`:

```
!> @defgroup groupname The parameters defined to convert R to Q
!> @{
real(wp),allocatable :: A(:)
integer,allocatable :: B(:)
integer,allocatable :: C(:)
!> @}
```

See, [the Doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) for details. The description should come pretty close to your comment.

Note that you can additionally add comments to the variables themselves.

---

Alternatively, you could use ["Member groups"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup):

```
!> @name groupname The parameters defined to convert R to Q
!> @{
real(wp),allocatable :: A(:)
integer,allocatable :: B(:)
integer,allocatable :: C(:)
!> @}
```

Comment: I used your suggestion. It groups nicely the variables. However, another tab for "Modules" is created, i.e., two "Modules" tab are present. One of them really contains the module and for the other the list contains "The parameters defined to convert R to Q". Is it what it supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. I prefer to use your second suggestion for fortran codes.